# Changing device configuration to display non-circular launcher icons

Tags: launcher, nexus-5x, app-icons, 7.1-nougat

According to [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/psa-android-7-1-circular-icon-support-is-determined-by-the-oem/) article, an Android device's "system framework decides whether or not to return either the regular icon or the round icon to the launcher."  "When a launcher requests an app icon, the framework returns either android:icon or android:roundIcon, depending on the device build configuration."

Is it possible to alter the device build configuration to change the default icon display to non-circular?

I'm on a stock, non-rooted Nexus 5X.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-rooted device, it's not possible as far as I've seen, as it's totally under control of OEM as implied in [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#circular-icons) Android developers documentation. But otherwise, it's possible if one can edit config with the value of [`config_useRoundIcon`](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/circular-icons.html) to `false`.

Just for experimenting, you can decompile the framework-res.apk and change the above-mentioned value in bools.txt and recompile the apk and push the apk into the device.